# Spectral radius of $I_d - \dfrac{w}{2} A$, simple calculation, tridiagonal matrix $A$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

We have $M^{-1} N = I_d - \dfrac{w}{2} A$ with $0 < w < 1$ and $A \in M_d(\mathbb{R})$ such as :

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 &  &  &  & \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 &  &  & \\ 
 & -1 & 2 & -1 &  & \\ 
 &  & ... & ... & ... & \\ 
 &  &  & -1 & 2 & -1\\ 
 &  &  &  & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_k = 4\sin^2\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{2(d+1)}\right)$.

I have two questions.
We have $\tilde{p}(w) = \max\left(1-w,\left|1-\dfrac{w}{2} \lambda_d\right|\right)$.

We have also $w_{\mathrm{opt}}  = \dfrac{2}{1+2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{d\pi}{2(d+1)}\right)}$.

I don't understand why $\tilde{p} (w_{\mathrm{opt}}) = \dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{2(d+1)}\right)}{2+\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{2(d+1)}\right)}$. I know it's simple calculation, but I don't understand...

And I have to calculate $\lim_{d \rightarrow +\infty} p(w_{\mathrm{opt}})$ with $p(w)$ the spectral radius of the matrix $M^{-1}N$.

Someone could help me ? Someone could explain to me the first point ? Thank you in advance.